# parse JSON to jq to get a list from AWS CLI

Tags: aws-cli, jq

I would like to get a list of task definitions I can create a list from via AWS CLI. Here is a partial list from the command;

`aws ecs list-task-definitions --region eu-west-1`

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArns": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:543573289192:task-definition/audience-view-dev-api:4", 
        "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:543573289192:task-definition/audience-view-dev-groups:4", 
        "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:543573289192:task-definition/audience-view-dev-groups:5", 
        "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:543573289192:task-definition/audience-view-dev-mock-api:1", 
        "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:543573289192:task-definition/audience-view-dev-mock-responder:1"
    ]
}
```

From this I would like to only show;

```
audience-view-dev-api
audience-view-dev-groups
audience-view-dev-groups
audience-view-dev-mock-api
audience-view-dev-mock-responder
```

I believe if I pipe this to `jq` then I can get what I'm after? I am trying various combinations of;  `aws ecs list-task-definitions --region eu-west-1 | jq -r '.taskDefinitionArns[].<something_here>'` to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get unique values:

```
aws ecs list-task-definitions | jq -r '.taskDefinitionArns[] | match(".*/([^:]+):[0-9]+$").captures[0].string' | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$ aws ecs list-task-definitions --region eu-west-1 \
  | jq -Mr '.taskDefinitionArns[] | split(":")[5] | split("/")[1]'
```

Expanded:

```
  .taskDefinitionArns[]     # for each taskDefinitionArns
| split(":")[5]             # take entry [5] after splitting by :
| split("/")[1]             # take entry [1] after splitting by /
```

Comment: Parsing using "5" looks brittle.  The sample data suggests it might be less brittle to extract the last ":"-delimited component, e.g. split(":")[-1]

Comment: Looking at [ListTaskDefinitions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ListTaskDefinitions.html) and [Amazon Resource Name (ARN)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) docs it's not clear.  I would have assumed the ARN format in play here is "arn:partition:service:region:account-id:resourcetype:resource" but it could also be "arn:partition:service:region:account-id:resourcetype/resource" (where "resource" contains a ":") so [RomanPerekhrest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46833048/8379597) might actually be better then this one.

Answer (score 3):

With **jq** **`match`** function:

```
aws ecs list-task-definitions --region eu-west-1 \
| jq -r '.taskDefinitionArns[] | match(".*/([^:]+):[0-9]+$").captures[0].string'
```

- `".*/([^:]+):[0-9]+$"` - regex pattern to match the sequence between `/` and the last `:` characters

---

The output:

```
audience-view-dev-api
audience-view-dev-groups
audience-view-dev-groups
audience-view-dev-mock-api
audience-view-dev-mock-responder
```

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#match(val),match(regex;flags)

Comment: Amazing!! May I ask where you learned this kung fu? Can you point me to a website(s) that may explain it better?

Comment: @eekfonky, welcome. Check the official `jq` manual https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/